# How many neurons should be there in the output layer of a neural network for classification?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have created a deep neural network for the classification of breast lesions. There are two possible outcomes. The lesion is either benign or malignant. My output layer is defined as below:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

My query is that should the number of layers in the output layer be 2 or 1? I have read a few articles where in some cases, the number of neurons in the output layer is the same as the number of class labels. Whereas in some blogs, the number of neurons should be 1 for a 2 class label(binary) problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using sigmoid, you want to use 1. If you use 2, use softmax. You can use either, but 1 is sufficient for a binary classification (usually you'd say if the value is smaller than 0.5 then it is class A, and if it is greater than 0.5 it is class B). Softmax on the other hand models each unit as a probability.

Notably as well, if you are using 2 units, you want to use categorical cross-entropy loss.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it implies 1 neuron is good enough without encouraging the reader to try both. In the real world either solution could work but there's an easy way to figure what works best without trying. 

I followed this answer for a current binary classification model I'm working on and using 2 neuron outputs (1 neuron for each class with softmax) than 1 neuron output (with a sigmoid activation func and 0.5 threshholding) worked significantly better. Try both!

Comment: @Omrii did you change the threshold from 0.5 based on ROC curves? Setting the correct threshold is much more important than deciding whether to use 1 or 2 output units. Both options are functionally identical, and it can be a huge waste of time to retrain and entire model if the training procedure is long. I actually do discourage trying both, one is not better than the other unless you're doing something else wrong (such as not setting the correct threshold).

Comment: Upon reading your reply I went to verify my work and I did find an error in my code (wrong tranpose call)! I Re-trained both and got 2 similarly behaving models (with thresholding). This answer still feels unsatisfactory though -- I recognize that functionally both output neuron counts behave the same, but if I'm aiming to maximize accuracy and willing to train both models on the offshoot the extra complexity the extra neuron gives yields slightly better accuracy, is it not worth it to try? What logical reasoning/proof that showcase what I've written prior won't happen?

Comment: @Omrii What you are proposing right now is to treat the number of output units as a hyperparameter. When training neural networks, the domain of trainable hyperparameters is infinite (because many of the hyperparameters are floating point numbers), so in general you want to spend your time varying only those hyperparameters that are worthwhile. If you do what you are proposing, you will **double** the number of models you have to train, for very little performance improvement. While you're not wrong that maybe there is some off chance that you will gain a negligible performance improvement...

Comment: ...you will be sacrificing trying a different hyperparameter that is more likely to have a much greater impact on performance. This will always be the case: because the domain of hyperparameters is infinite, you have to decide how much time you are willing to spend trying all combinations. So, if you decide you are willing to wait up to 5 hours for all the configurations to complete, you are suggesting that **TWO AND A HALF HOURS** of that time goes towards this one particular parameter --- unless you choose to train this hyperparameter only once, after choosing all other hyperparameters...

Comment: ...but in that case you would have to decide ahead of time the number of outputs to use in the first place: one or two. Which seems like something you wouldn't want to do based on your comments.

**TLDR**: if you have infinite time, you can try anything you want and you might see a small improvement in performance. But in practice, training a hyperparameter that has negligible performance improvements will mean not experimenting with some other hyperparameter that actually has the potential to improve your model in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible outcomes. Positive and negative.

This can be done with both 1 node or 2 nodes. If you are using one node you can define a threshold (0.5 is very common) and outputs greater than or equal that threshold will classified as positive or else negative.

And also you can use two nodes. node 0 for positive and node 1 for negative. You have to get the result related to the node with highest value out of the two outputs of the output layer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a 'proven' correct answer to this question, you just need to try both (ie. hyperparameter tuning!) and see which one yields a better model.

- When creating your model with 1 neuron output, apply a Sigmoid function at the end of your model.
- When creating your model with 2 neuron outputs, apply a Softmax function at the end of your model.

To make the writing of your 'testing' code easier, you can ignore and trim the  the 'False' class neuron when testing the 2 neuron output model, since the 'True' class neuron effectively represents the same signal as the 1 neuron output of your 1 neuron output model (and then you can still use thresholding)